# Getting a href from a button

Tags: jquery, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract the href from certain buttons from [this url](https://www.iefp.pt/ofertas-emprego) (the buttons are located bellow the h4 "Ofertas Disponíveis".
[image]

These buttons have an onclick function called "updateJobModal(button_index)" but I can't locate the function.
At the end of the tag, an "ev" button appears to be related to JQuery.

How can I obtain the attribute in this case?

Comment: `$("#jobOffer588769886").find("a").attr("href")`

Comment: https://www.iefp.pt/Jobs-portlet/js/job.js ..... u will find that function on this link

Comment: @Black Sorry, I wasn't clear enough with my question, the href I'm looking for is the one that gets redirected once you click in one of those buttons. Not the actual attribute href (which is javascript:void(0);)

Comment: @Rush.2707 Is there a way to get the redirected href that you get from that function using xpath? I have no clue on how to do it for this example

Comment: Please include all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started 
function in:  https://www.iefp.pt/Jobs-portlet/js/job.js?browserId=other&minifierType=js

Specifically:

```
function updateJobModal(a){currentAjax=jobListAjax;updateCurrentJobModal(search_job_offers[a])}
```